# Blender 3.0 doesn't give me the option to load 2.93 settings

Tags: customization

I just downloaded Blender 3.0 and usually when downloading a new version I'd get a button the the splash screen allowing me to load my previous version's settings, but I don't have this button in 3.0. Is this happening with anyone else? Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Had you already tried the 3.0 alpha or beta version before? Blender stores the preferences in the user's home directory. It's "C:\Users\ *<username>* \AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender" for Windows. When there is already a 3.0 folder it will use it. Else Blender checks for older preferences and asks if you want to import them.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: I was having this same issue. But I am using the portable version, and am wondering if this makes a difference regarding Blunder's solution. I've always used the portable version, and have never had this problem before.

Comment: I was noticing that some UI colors were not as I had set them in 2.93 when I first opened them in 3.0. I also wasn't prompted to use 2.93's settings. So based on Blunder's advice, I found and deleted the 3.0 folder, and opened Blender 3.0 again. This time, it prompted me to load the 2.93 settings, so I thought I was good. But when I get in, all my UI colors are just as they were when first opening 3.0, meaning not as they were in 2.93. This leads me to wonder if 3.0 loaded any of my other 2.93 settings.